# Как передавать дополнительные параметры массивом в fetch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

Есть экшн(использую `react+redux`)например:

```
export const getUsers = ()  => (dispatch, getState) => {

    let url = 'request?path=/user_params&params%5Bgroups%5D%5B%5D=main&params%5Bgroups%5D%5B%5D=users_relations_user';

    return fetch(url, {
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        method: 'GET',
    }).then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => dispatch(receiveUsers(json))).catch(function (error) {
            console.log('Request failure: ', error);
        });

};
```

В данном случае в url  я захардкодил параметры. Ранее в jquery эти параметры передавал с помощью массива:

```
$.ajax({
 data: array,
 url: ...})
```

А в массив уже прописывал параметры:

```
a = {
 groups: [
   'main',
   'users_relations_user'
 ]
}
```

Можно ли так сделать в `whatwg-fetch`(использую его). Если да, то как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) принимает вторым аргументом объект `init`, в котором есть свойство `body`. Через него можно передать данные (тело) запроса, в том числе в виде параметров URL - для этого используется интерфейс [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams). Он конечно не может как jquery делать строку параметров из массива. Вам придется вручную (либо в цикле) добавлять каждый параметр методом [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/append) или [`set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/set). Либо сразу передать готовую строку параметров в конструктор `URLSearchParams`.

*Замечание*: свойство `body` можно использовать только для запросов с данными (`POST`, `PUT`, ...). Для GET запросов его нельзя использовать.

Comment: как быть в таком случае с GET  зарпосами,если body используется только в POST\PUT?(если нужно получить определенные данные по определенным параметрам)

Comment: _как быть в таком случае с GET зарпосами..._ Никак. вернее, так же как вы делаете это сейчас: добавляете строку параметров к URL. Ну или используйте jquery

Comment: вы правы. либо самому какой-то метод придумать, который будт этот ur динамично форировать растаскивая массив,либо jquery. спасибо за ответ

Comment: см. мой ответ ниже

Answer (score 1):

К счастью, всё уже написано до нас :-)

```
import { stringify  } from 'qs';

const queryParams = {
  user: 'test',
  userParams: {
    name: 'test',
    values: [1,2,3]
  }
}

const host = 'http://localhost/123';

const url = `${host}/${stringify(queryParams)}`;

http://localhost/123/user=test&userParams%5Bname%5D=test&userParams%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D=1&userParams%5Bvalues%5D%5B1%5D=2&userParams%5Bvalues%5D%5B2%5D=3
```